# Facebook API status_update permission

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I wrote an application to check if a specified Facebook page (by user) exists, namely it`s real. Namely, the user fills the page url and the API posts something on that page and then check for the existence of that post, based on id received when posted.
Used the following permissions to do that:

```
protected static $permissions = array('scope' => 'email, manage_pages, publish_actions, status_update');
```

After a few months of 'normal' functioning, it seems that out of the clear blue sky, `status_update` is no longer a valid Facebook permission. If I remove it from the array, I receive the following error:
`Facebook\FacebookPermissionException: (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action`. Any ideas?

Comment: Why would you _make a post_ purely to check the _existence_ of a page? That does make very little sense IMHO.

Comment: @CBroe Yes, I know it sounds strange and maybe stupid...it's actually our client's idea, and it's blunt as the client is :) This is used for companies that are registered on a platform; one of the fields must be filled with company's Facebook Page and the application should verify if this page is real or not by posting something on it and then checking the wall for that post. Hope now it`s a little bit clear.

Comment: You can read the details of the Facebook page from the API via its page name or page id – isn’t that enough to check if it’s “real”?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no permission called `status_update`, only `publish_actions` is needed to publish something on the user wall. If you want to post "as Page", you need `publish_pages`.

It´s not "out of the clear blue sky", `status_update` is deprecated since many years already. You may have missed the v2.0 upgrade.